# Activate Conda environment

Tags: python, conda

I have installed Anaconda on Windows. I try need to activate conda environment but I do not know how. Coud you anybody advice how to do it step by step? I got this message:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: what's the output of `conda` in cmd?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Anaconda's documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) for creating and activating conda environments. You'll want to first create the environment, then activate it. Depending on your OS, versioning, environment `%PATH`, etc you may have other questions. However this is a good place to start.

Note that if using powershell, first use `conda init` and restart powershell before trying to create and activate the environment as documented [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8428)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in a anaconda promt then just use command

```
activate venv  #venv is my environment
```